# Does WCF FaultException<T> support interop with a Java web service Fault

Tags: java, .net, wcf, interop, apache-axis

I have written a java axis2 1.4.1 web service and .net 3.5 WCF client and I am trying to catch the wsdl faults thrown.

Unlike .net 2.0 the .net 3.5 claims to support `wsdl:fault` and the service reference wizard does generate all the correct fault classes in the client proxy. But when I try to catch a fault it doesn't seem to correctly serialise so that I can only `catch (FaultException ex)` and not the type I actually threw using `FaultException<T>`

I had a look inside my reference.cs I can see wizard has added correct `FaultContract` to the my opeation.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/Foo", ConfigurationName="FooServiceProxy.Foo")]
public interface Foo {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://www.mycomp.com/Foo/list", ReplyAction="*")]
 [System.ServiceModel.FaultContractAttribute(typeof(TestWsdlFaultsApp.FooServiceProxy.SimpleFault), Action="http://www.mycomp.com/Foo/list", Name="simpleFault")]
        [System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute()]
        TestWsdlFaultsApp.FooServiceProxy.listResponse list(TestWsdlFaultsApp.FooServiceProxy.listRequest request);
    }
```

Is there something else I need to do in .net to get this to work? or does WCF only support custom wsdl faults from a .net web service ?

Heres my wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wsdl-viewer.xsl"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="FooImplDefinitions"
      targetNamespace="http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/Foo"
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
      xmlns:tns="http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/Foo"
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

      <!-- TYPES -->
      <wsdl:types>
            <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.mycomp.com/wsdl/Foo"
                  elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
                  xmlns:security="http://www.mycomp.com/xsd/types/Security">

                  <!-- IMPORTS -->
                  <xs:import namespace="http://www.mycomp.com/xsd/types/Foo"
                        schemaLocation="Foo.xsd" />
                   <xs:import namespace="http://www.mycomp.com/xsd/types/Security"
                        schemaLocation="Security.xsd" />

                  <!-- HEADER ELEMENTS -->
                  <xs:element name="identity" type="security:TrustedIdentity" />

                  <!-- REQUEST/RESPONSE ELEMENTS -->
                  <xs:element name="listRequest">
                        <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="action" type="xs:string" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>
                  <xs:element name="listResponse">
                        <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="stuff" type="xs:string" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                  </xs:element>

                  <!-- FAULT TYPES  -->
                  <xs:complexType name="SimpleFault">
                        <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="reason" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>

                  <!-- FAULT ELEMENTS -->
                  <xs:element name="simpleFault" type="tns:SimpleFault"/>
            </xs:schema>
      </wsdl:types>

      <!-- MESSAGES -->
      <wsdl:message name="listRequest">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:listRequest" name="parameters" />
            <wsdl:part element="tns:identity" name="header" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="listResponse">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:listResponse" name="return" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="simpleException">
            <wsdl:part element="tns:simpleFault" name="fault"/>
      </wsdl:message>

      <!-- PORT TYPES -->
      <wsdl:portType name="Foo">
            <wsdl:operation name="list">
                  <wsdl:input message="tns:listRequest" />
                  <wsdl:output message="tns:listResponse" />
                  <wsdl:fault name="simpleFault" message="tns:simpleException" />
            </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>

      <!-- BINDINGS -->
      <wsdl:binding name="FooBinding" type="tns:Foo">
            <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
            <wsdl:operation name="list">
                  <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.mycomp.com/Foo/list" />
                  <wsdl:input>
                        <soap:header message="tns:listRequest" part="header" use="literal" />
                        <soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:input>
                  <wsdl:output>
                        <soap:body use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:output>
                  <wsdl:fault name="simpleFault">
                        <soap:fault name="simpleFault" use="literal" />
                  </wsdl:fault>
            </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>

      <!-- SERVICES -->
      <wsdl:service name="FooServiceImpl">
            <wsdl:port name="FooPort" binding="tns:FooBinding">
                  <soap:address
                        location="http://localhost:9001/Foo/FooServiceImpl" />
            </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks john you set me on the right path, Problem was obvious: I was not setting the detail when I threw the fault in java (axis2).

DODGY CODE:

```
throw new SimpleException("SimpleFault thrown");
```

WORKING CODE:

```
 SimpleFault fault = new SimpleFault();
 fault.setReason("SimpleFault reason");

 SimpleFaultE faultMessage = new SimpleFaultE();
 faultMessage.setSimpleFault(fault);

 SimpleException ex = new SimpleException("SimpleFault thrown");
 ex.setFaultMessage(faultMessage);

 throw ex;
```

So AXIS2 -> WCF  wsdl:fault interop works just fine...

Answer (score 1):

WCF should work with axis2 exceptions. I had it working, but I don't remember all the details.

When you use SOAP monitor or something like that, what do you see in the fault message body?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not catching the `FaultException<T>`, that means you're likely not sending it. Be careful of the XML namespace being used. Take a look at what  you're sending, using Fiddler or something like it.

`FaultException<T>` works fine with Java, or even with WCF.